# Visual Studio Code deletes my library line inclusion when saving automatically

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I am programming C in Visual Studio Code, but I have this annoying problem. When Visual Studio Code automatically saves my work, it deletes the line that has the library inclusion that I need. So when I compile, it gives me an error that I did not specify the function.

How can I resolve it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Show your code as a [mre]. What exactly are you doing, what happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have installed a corrupted version of Visual Studio Code or the library files of the Visual Studio Code and then location where you are saving your programs might be in different location. For example

The library files of Visual Studio Code might be on the C: drive and the program files might be in an [OneDrive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OneDrive)  folder.

Try reinstalling it from an authentic source if the second stated problem is not the case. If the problem still continues then please comment down on my reply.

Reinstall either from Microsoft store or from
*[Download Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download)*.

Comment: I'm using manjaro XFCE DESKTOP version and the extension of 42 header in vscode. I noticed that when I write "#include <unistd.h>" below the header, vscode autosave and delete the line; but when I write on the second line below the header the line doesn't get cancelled. Is a problem of the extension of vscode?

Comment: you mean when you write the 2nd line then.... the #include<unistd.h> does not gets deleted??
if that is the case then it is not an extension problem

Comment: /* ************************************************************************** */ (the end of the header)
(empty line)
#include <unistd.h>.if I write like this it is not deleted with the automatic saving. If instead so./* ************************************************************************** */
#include <unistd.h>

Comment: however I resolved leaving a blank line